# Passing parameters through an RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard, bookdown

I am looking to create unique/individual reports for a given list of vendors. The ideal output format would be a seperate html file of the given vendors information.

The issue is that I am having trouble wrapping my head around creating parameterized reports in RMarkdown. I have been taking a look at this [link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html) to understand how to loop/iterate through RMarkdown reports

To illustrate and share the logic of what I want to execute is the following:

```
for (vendor in vendor.name) {
  rmarkdown::render('input.Rmd', params = list(vendor = vendor))
}
```

Where I then have a print out of:

```
Vendor-1.html, Vendor-2.html, …, Vendor-4.html, and vendor-4.html
```

Which then gets saved locally to my computer. The part I have wrapping my head around is say we have a bar graph of sales by month, how would the parameter passing through the entire document know when to change the the vendor number for a unique view.

If anyone can share an example either iris, mtcars, or any base dataset within R I would really appreciate it. Looking at how this workflow/logic would work because I am struggling to understand the concept.

To specify, say I have this chunck of code here. How would the params$vendor function know to loop over another vendor if I am not calling it within the chunk. Within my dplyr verbs on my filter should I do  , MVNDR_NBR == qc_sales$vendor_number or params$vendor? This is the piece that has me most confounded

```
sales_2021_stock <- qc_sales %>%
    filter(FSCL_YR == 2021
          , STR_NBR != '8119'
          , MAPPED_ORD_SRC  == 'QC'
          , so_flg == 0
          , YTLW_TY_LY_FLG == 'TY'
          , MVNDR_NBR == '60031167'
          , !SUB_DEPT_NBR %in% c('0025','0028')) %>% 
  group_by(MVNDR_NBR, MVNDR_NM, FSCL_WK_NBR, FSCL_YR) %>%  
  summarise(Sales = sum(ESVS_NET_SLS)) %>%  
  mutate(FSCL_YR = as.character(FSCL_YR)) %>%  
  collect()

sales_2020_stock <- qc_sales %>%
    filter(FSCL_YR == 2020
          , STR_NBR != '8119'
          , MAPPED_ORD_SRC  == 'QC'
          , YTLW_TY_LY_FLG == 'LY'
          , so_flg == 0
          , MVNDR_NBR == '60031167'
          , !SUB_DEPT_NBR %in% c('0025','0028')) %>% 
  group_by(MVNDR_NBR, MVNDR_NM, FSCL_WK_NBR, FSCL_YR) %>%  
  summarise(Sales = sum(ESVS_NET_SLS)) %>%  
  mutate(FSCL_YR = as.character(FSCL_YR)) %>%  
  collect()

sales_comp_line_stock <-  rbind(sales_2021_stock, sales_2020_stock)


stock_comp <-  ggplot(sales_comp_line_stock, aes(x = FSCL_WK_NBR, y = Sales, color = FSCL_YR ))+
  geom_line(size = 1.25, aes(color = FSCL_YR))+
  geom_smooth(size = .50, aes(color = FSCL_YR), se = FALSE, method = "auto")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,weeks,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format(scale = .0001, suffix = "K"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0298F9", "#F96302"))+
  theme_economist()+
   ggtitle('Week-Over-Week Sales (Stock) 2021 v 2020')+
    theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(linetype = "dotted"),
    axis.text = element_text( size = 10),
    legend.position = c(0, 1),legend.justification = c(0, 1),
    plot.title = element_text( size = 14, margin=margin(0,0,20,0), hjust = 0.5),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
     strip.text = element_text(size=10)
  )

stock_comp
```

My dataset looks as follows, these are the same vendors included in my parameter, how would I create a ggplot displaying sales month over month  printed into an individual html output?:

Ideally one plot would be written like this:

```
ggplot(sample_vendor_tbl, aes(x = FSCL_MTH_NM, y = Sales)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

To print out multiple ggplots within a document I would do the following:

```
for (i in vendor_nbr){
  ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Month, y = sales))+
geom_col()
}
```

I am just confused here when we need to accounting for the parameter. How can I create a plot for the given vendor for its print out, similar to the example posted in your answer. I basically want to do exactly what you did in your answer with the charts but leveraging ggplot instead of base R

To create a ggplot using parameters I had to pull in params$mvndr_nbr into my dplyr verbs as follows:

```
sample_vendor_tbl %>%  
  filter(MVNDR_NBR == params$MVNDR_NBR) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = FSCL_MTH_NM, y = Sales)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: Within the document, it should be referencing `params$vendor` whenever something needs to be personalized. If there are more parameters that are useful to identify the vendor, then perhaps `render(.., params=list(vendor="somename",vendorid="someguid"))`, and in the document you conditionally generate reports such as `if (!is.null(params$someguid)) { dat <- subset(globaldata, vendorid==params$vendorid); ...; }`.

Comment: So params$vendor would be my list of vendors, correct? Say I have a ggplot or dplyr calculation, how would those functions know when to use the given parameter when it is passing through it. Would I need to do params$vendor within my dplyr verbs or ggplot naming/title conventions

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is similar yet different to this: https://rpubs.com/santic_113/587686 . Here I looped over every plot giving me a unique view. I am trying to print and unique html document/views WITHIN the document to the specific vendor

Comment: Is it possible you can share an example with an dataset within base R?

Comment: No, `params@vendor` is *this* report's vendor. Not all of them, just this one. Think of a report as a function, and things that are passed in `params` are the function parameters. All code within the report only knows what it's been given, so `params$vendor` should be a singular vendor.

Comment: On short notice, I don't think I can do better than the brief `params$state` example in the link you provided (nor do I have the time to contrive something, sorry).

Comment: Then how can I iterate with a list of vendors providing me a unique print out of the given vendors information?

Comment: What's wrong with your `for (vendor in list_of_vendors) render("doc.Rmd", params=list(vendor=vendor))`? That provides you a single vendor, on which your report should subset/filter all of its data in its plots. If your report is always using all data and showing all data, then that's on you.

Comment: Ive not actually tried this example because I am not fully understanding how to iterate still but I updated my question with some code, I really appreciate it

Comment: From your description it sounded as though the vendor names were in a text file and you needed to read from a system file with something like `read.table` or `read.csv`. If that's no the case then post complete code that sets up a working example.

Comment: Okay, I will try a reproduceable example with a basic dataset but I dont know how to iterate over a markdown file. I know you can for (year in 2000:2020) {
    render_one(state, year)
  }
} for example but I am trying to understand how to structure my code within the RMarkdown document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the step you were missing was specifying the output filename so that each "vendor" would have its own file; otherwise, the same filename is overwritten each time leaving you with a single HTML document.

An example:

````
---
title: mtcars cyl
author: r2evans
params:
  cyl: null
---

We have chosen to plot a histogram of `mtcars` where `$cyl` is equal to `r params$cyl`:

```{r}
dat <- subset(mtcars, cyl == params$cyl)
if (nrow(dat) > 0) {
  hist(dat$disp)
}
```
````

Calling this with:

```r
for (cy in c(4,6,8)) {
  rmarkdown::render("~/StackOverflow/10466439/67525642.Rmd", 
                    output_file = sprintf("cyl_%s.html", cy),
                    params = list(cyl = cy))
}
```

will render three HTML files, `cyl_4.html`, `cyl_6.html`, and `cyl_8.html`, each with differing content:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! This makes sense

Comment: This was the exact example I was looking for, sorry for the confusion on my end

Comment: is it possible if you can share an example using ggplot? I have been able to reproduce your example with my data using hist but unsure how to loop over when I am using ggplot

Comment: You likely need to switch from `aes(.)` to `aes_string(.)` and using strings of variable names instead of symbols. For instance, if you're trying `ggplot(mydata, aes(x, params$vendor))` (which will fail), then you likely need something like `ggplot(mydata, aes_string("x", params$vendor))`.

Comment: The part where I get confused is where do I call the parameter? Say I want to show a simple bar or col graph. Sales month over month. My month would be on my x-axis and sales would be on my y-axis. Where within ggplot(my data, aes(x = month, y = sales)+ geom_col do I insert the parameter call so that the ggplot plots only data specific to the parameter?

Comment: *"call the parameter"* makes no sense to me. If I understand, then your `params$vendor` is just a length-1 string, there's no way to call it in this context. I *still* have no idea what your data looks like, but I *suspect* (and demonstrated) that you may need to filter/subset your data before plotting. Perhaps you need `tempdat <- subset(mydata, vendor == params$vendor); ggplot(tempdata, ...)+geom_col()`?

Comment: Sure, I will post an update of the data in the post

Comment: When I try `tempdat <- subset(mydata, vendor == params$vendor)` I get the following error `Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 24 but subscript `i` has size 0.`

Comment: I can reproduce that error with `subset(as_tibble(mtcars), cyl == NULL)`, suggesting you are not using the correct `params$` name. If you are truly using `render(..., params=list(vendor=60074051))`, then you should be using `tempdat <- subset(mydata, MVNDR_NBR == params$vendor)`. Also, `ggplot` plots within `for` loops need to be explicitly printed, such as `for (v in ...) { gg <- ggplot(...) + geom_col(); print(gg); }`.

Comment: Im unsure how, I am using the correct `params$` , but I still get the same error

Comment: Okay, I resolved the subset error, however I am still completely lost as to how I can create a simple bar chart using ggplot