# How to use date to knit individual R Markdown reports?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown document that I'm using to create a report that gets distributed a few days per week. Rather than overwriting the same knitted file over and over again and renaming it manually in File Explorer, I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to how I can use the same R Markdown document to knit unique reports based the date they are generated.

Like the basic example below, my report contains a line of code that takes the most recent date in my data, and I'd like to use this value to create individual knitted files to PDF rather than overwriting the same one over and over again. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

````
---
title: "Test Doc"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
date_today <- "25-11-2023"
```

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: It looks like you need a parameterised template.  You can use that to generate your regular reports.  See [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html) for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters through an RMarkdown document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525642/passing-parameters-through-an-rmarkdown-document)

Comment: Those links are helpful, @Limey, but I'm still having trouble understanding how I can apply those answers to my scenario where I just want to add the current date to the end of my Test.pdf document. Are you able to provide a working example for me? Thanks.

Comment: You could first extract the most recent date in your data, and then call the markdown with `rmarkdown::render` using this date as parameter and to name the new file

Answer (score -1):

Save the following as `template.Rmd` in your working directory

````
---
title: "Template document"
date: "25/11/2023"
output: html_document
params:
  company: null
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## `r params$company` Report
This is a report on `r params$company`.  It was generated on `r Sys.Date()`.
````

Now run the following code in RStudio (or any editor of your choice.

```
companies <- paste("Company", 1:3)

for (c in companies) {
  fileName <- paste0(str_replace(c, " ", ""), "_", format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m%d"), ".html")
  rmarkdown::render(
    "template.Rmd", 
    output_file = fileName,
    params = list(company = c)
  )
}
```

Three HTML files will be created in your current working directory.  Their names will be `Company1_<yyyymmdd>.html`, `Company2_<yyyymmdd>.html` and `Company3_<yyyymmdd>.html`.  The content of each will indicate to which company the report relates.

That's the principle.  You should be able to adapt it to your own specific use case.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, @Limey, but this doesn't answer my question. I have one date that I want to use to name the file, so I'm not sure how a for loop is applicable here. If my "master" Markdown file is named Test.Rmd, all I want to do is rename the knitted version Test_2023-11-26.pdf, or whatever the current date is.

Comment: Then simply remove the loop.